# EF Core - how to update an entry and its related many-to-many relationship?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

In EF Core I want to update an entry of type `tableA` which contains a list of `tableB` type entities (bound by a many-to-many relationship). My approach is: select the entity from the DB, change the attributes (included the list of `tableB` objects) and apply `SaveChange`s to update the database.
The problem is: when I try to do so, I get the error:

> SqlException: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_tableAtableB'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'tableAtableB'. The duplicate key value is (1, 42).

Does anyone know how to solve this problem? I would prefer not to add explicitly the join table as a class.

Here some code:

```
public async Task<tableA> UpdateAsync(tableA newItem, CancellationToken ct = default)
{
    using(var context = m_ContextFactory.CreateDbContext())
    {
        var itemDb = context.tableA
               .FirstOrDefault(l => l.Id == newItem.Id);
        
        itemDb.tableBlist = newItem.tableBlist;
        var t = await context.SaveChangesAsync(ct);

        return await context.tableA
                .AsNoTracking()
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == newItem.Id, ct);
    }
}
```

I tried to operate on the tracking states of the entities but with poor results.

Comment: Please share some code showing how exactly you do that.

Comment: Post your code. EF Core deals with objects and entities, not tables. *All* changes made to objects loaded by a DbContext will be persisted when `SaveChanges` is called. There won't be any attempt to *insert* them. `I tried to operate on the tracking states` that's what can *cause* such a problem

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved:

1. clear the `itemDb.tableBlist`;
2. save changes and close the DB context;
3. open a new context;
4. load again the `itemDb` and copy the `tableBlist` from `newItem`, then
   save.

It's not probably the most correct/elegant solution but it seems to work.